# How can I edit a 'binary' XML file?

Tags: xml, editor

It's not really a programming question, but I want to edit some of the ['binary' XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) files on Windows. Is there a stand-alone viewer/editor for 'binary' XML file?

Comment: Ahem, what do you mean with 'binary XML'? Have I missed something?

Comment: When I open xml file, there are a lot of binary data embedded in it Probably encrypted as well.

Comment: Then it's not XML. Ask your money back from Microsoft.

Comment: Uhm… xml files are per definition *always plain text*. If it's not, its probably not xml.

It is possible to embedd binary data inside (like images) which is mostly done using base64 encryption.

Comment: ...or more likely, like James B suggests, your current editor has some serious encoding problems. Use Notepad++ as a reference editor.

Comment: @Nils: Even in the case of embedding, the embedded data is not allowed to contain arbitrary bytes, like \0. Hence the base64 encoding.

Comment: @jhwist: [Don't tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **[FI](https://fi.dev.java.net/)** can help you, and you can check [this video](http://www.noemax.com/products/free_utilities/fi_converter.html) (you can convert binary XML to XML, edit XML, and you can convert XML to Binary XML),
- it is not free, but you can check **[Stylus](http://www.stylusstudio.com/binary_xml.html)**,
- maybe **[Jujuedit](http://www.jujusoft.com/software/edit/index.html)** can help you

Comment: @javaloper: I tried this but it showed squares for binary xml file. No text.

Comment: You can try FI if file is Binary XML file. If this can't help you, i don't know about that file type.

Comment: These links are broken

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to be able to edit?....If you open the file and you get squares for the characters, then it is likely that the bytes do not correspond to a character in the default charset of the editor you are using, so it is unlikely that you could view or make meaningful edits to the file anyway

Comment: JamesB, I don't get squares in notepad++. That was my answer to javaloper regarding Jujuedit.

Comment: You can edit binary data just fine. Just because it's not in a text format does not mean it's not editable. Simply load and decode.

Answer (score 1):

[Binary XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) files have been around a long time.  They are typically used in programs where the response times of text-based XML files is insufficient - like [Lidar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar), [sonar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonar), or scan data.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.