# XML file editing problem

Tags: xml

I've a directory consisting of .xml files only, installed by a third party application. While I can read and edit some of the XML files, some are not readable in Notepad++/Notepad. In Notepad++, I see [this http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b445db1c84.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b445db1c84.png) for one of them. These files are not corrupted, for sure.

I somewhere read that this might be encrypted XML?

**EDIT:**

**I tried 'file' command but found nothing useful. I've uploaded one file [here](http://dc167.4shared.com/download/176948902/5c6f0d34/schemeL.xml?tsid=20091219-185205-84472e1). It's less than 1KB. Could someone please help me with this file?**

Comment: Sure does look like encryption or compression.  The format's not clear, though.

Answer (score 0):

It could imaginably be encrypted; alternatively, Notepad could just be using the wrong code page. Have you tried the usual suspects for possible encodings?

Comment: @Joe: could you please suggest the usual suspects?

Comment: I'm not sure how much control of this Notepad even gives you, but for example this could be UTF-16 looked at as if it were some 8-bit format.

I guess the leading suspects are (in no particular order) UTF-16, UTF-8, maybe UTF-32, Code page 1252. But there are a ton of others: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752010%28VS.85%29.aspx. Naturally, most of these shouldn't be used for XML, but it's hard to know what's wrong with an unreadable file.

Comment: @joe: I tried to play with all the available encodings (including mentioned by you) in Firefox but none of them worked.

Comment: Oh, well. Then it's looking like it is indeed encrypted or compressed. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using file or a similar utility to guess the file's actual type/encoding. If you don't have the file command, you can download it from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm
(Notepad++ may provide similar functionality, I'm not familiar with Notepad++ other than recognizing the name)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything using Python and the typical UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, ISO-8859-1 or Windows code page 1252.  I checked out the file, hoping it was a simple XOR encryption, but it wasn't.  Perhaps the file is corrupt?  Can you open it in a normal Windows text editor and view its contents at all?  Does Internet Explorer have any trouble displaying the file?

Comment: @Dustin: I tried these encodings in Firefox by renaming file to a text file. Characters looked very similar to as I posted in question. Normal notepad only shows boxes.

Comment: Here's a dumb question: what are these files **supposed** to contain?

Comment: @Michael: it is suppose to contain XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance this could be the [Binary XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) format which stackoverflow was discussing [just the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913318/how-to-edit-binary-xml-file)?

Comment: @anbrose: It was me who started that thread but later I figured this was not that 'binary XML' because I played with all the mentioned technology in 'binary XML' and it didn't work.